# Stopping the Gag Reflex: How and why does it work?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, reflexes

I was talking to some friends over the weekend, and one of them made a comment about gagging. He said that he read or watched that clenching your thumb with your other fingers (making a tight fist with your thumb in the middle) stops your gag reflex. So, naturally, as a bunch of stupid teenagers, all 7 of us proceed to do this while shoving our fingers down our throats as far as possible. None of us had a gag reflex.

Why does this work? it seems totally random and weird.

Comment: It might work because it distracts you. When you have a gastroscopy (stomach investigation) in hospital, the nurses try to make you focus on other parts of your body ("try to relax your legs"). It helps.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought at first too. Just tried it while looking at my leg, and that also worked. Can you add that as an answer with some some source so I can mark it answered?

Comment: is this relatable to jendrassiks?